# Asp.net mvc error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have created an asp.net MVC website with databases. I recently added an identity database. Everything works fine on my machine. However, when I run it on another computer it gives me this error:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.'`

[image: Screenshot]

**This is my AccountController**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;
        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userMgr,
                       SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInMgr)
        {
            userManager = userMgr;
            signInManager = signInMgr;
            IdentitySeedData.EnsurePopulated(userMgr).Wait();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ViewResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new LoginModel
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            });
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityUser user =
                await userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.Name);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                    if ((await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user,
                    loginModel.Password, false, false)).Succeeded)
                    {
                        return Redirect(loginModel?.ReturnUrl ?? "/Admin/Index");
                    }
                }
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid name or password");
            return View(loginModel);
        }

        public async Task<RedirectResult> Logout(string returnUrl = "/")
        {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
    }
```

**This is my IdentitySeedData**

```
public class IdentitySeedData
    {
        private const string adminUser = "Admin";
        private const string adminPassword = "Secret123$";

        public static async Task EnsurePopulated(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {

            IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(adminUser);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new IdentityUser("Admin");
                await userManager.CreateAsync(user, adminPassword);
            }
        }
    }
```

The error when run on another computer always generates itself here:

```
 public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userMgr,
                       SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInMgr)
        {
            userManager = userMgr;
            signInManager = signInMgr;
            IdentitySeedData.EnsurePopulated(userMgr).Wait();
        }
```

A link to the project:

https://github.com/DemarioDouce/SoccerClub

I would love to know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppIdentityDbContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

just add this to the startup.cs within here:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I go through same issue. some time user create customize class for membership hence asp.net dont create AspNetUsers table.

For example :

```
public class Member : IdentityUser
{
    Public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Try to tag your IdentityUser table

```
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
public class Member : IdentityUser
{
    Public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

I hope this works for you as it did for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added a member class as was illustrated. However, I got the same error. I will be adding a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well. Another alternative solution that I haven't seen mentioned is to just create a new database migration. If you have the [EF Core CLI tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) installed, you can just run `dotnet ef migrations add AddedEFCoreTables` followed by `dotnet ef database update`. This will add the SQL tables needed for user authentication with ASP.NET Core Identity and EF Core. However, I think this is only useful if you're working with a persistent database and don't want to keep building up the database every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. I did not yet perform migration on the database.